# Origami app for smartphones

Tags: android, ios, game, educational, visual-design

I am looking for an origami making app for smatphones such as Android and iOS.

In the app, I should be able to click on an icon or button to create a new origami. These are creations made out of square pieces of paper by folding them and sometimes cutting.

When I do this, the app should be able to take me though the following steps:

- Choose paper color (or paper color with pattern). The user should be able to choose this separately for both the front side and the back side of the paper.
- The user should then be able to choose an origami creation (dog, cat, pig, frog, etc...)
- The user should then be able to view the steps in a list.
- Below, the user can choose to go through the steps, in (A) guided, (B) unguided, or (C) 3D paper handling mode. The user can click done to save origami.
- The user can choose to play in 3D with origamis done). In this mode, you can choose the orgamis you made, place them on surfaces, hold them, and make them interact.

When creating the origami, you can (i) drag to make each fold into a line from a drag, or (ii) you can choose a mode where you pin a paper part to grab it and then drag the grab to the fold location and press down on the paper (this interaction mode should be more realistic).

Where can I find such software?

Who is willing to implement it?

Kids could really benefit (and, enjoy), from this.

Thanks.